# AngularJS controller initialization problems when switching from $scope to "controller as" form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When switching from $scope to "controller as" syntax, I run into trouble with the "this" reference.  I need to call to a service to get some data for the initial page load up.  But the "this" I get refers to the global window object rather than an instance of the exercise controller.  Kind of weird.  Here's what I know.

The AngularJS inclusion in my main page...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Here's how the controller gets included into the template page.

```
 <div class="col-xs-9" 
      ng-include="'exercise/exercise_body.html'" 
      ng-show="mainController.showStatus.exercises" 
      ng-controller="ExerciseController as ec" 
      ng-init="ec.initialize()"></div>
```

Here is the initialize function from the ExerciseController.

```
this.initialize = function(){
    // Item lists to display on different parts of the page
    this.dataList = {};
    this.dataList.exercises = [];
    this.dataList.resources = [];

    var promise = exerciseService.getExercises();
    promise.then(function(res){
        console.log(this); // this is a window object?  why????
        this.dataList.exercises = res.data.exercises;
    });
}
```

And lastly, there is the stack trace from Chrome....

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'exercises' of undefined
at app.js:82
at angular.js:13189
at l.$eval (angular.js:14401)
at l.$digest (angular.js:14217)
at l.$apply (angular.js:14506)
at l (angular.js:9659)
at S (angular.js:9849)
at XMLHttpRequest.D.onload (angular.js:9790)
```

So what that leaves me with is a datalist object that's undefined even after setting a definition explicitly.  Any ideas on what can be done to fix this or work around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This is very typical problem. The way callback function is provided to promise will get it called in global context. You need to bind callback function to controller context:

```
var promise = exerciseService.getExercises();
promise.then(function(res) {
    this.dataList.exercises = res.data.exercises;
}.bind(this));
```

or simply use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that preserves lexical scope:

```
var promise = exerciseService.getExercises();
promise.then(res => this.dataList.exercises = res.data.exercises);
```

Comment: Another pattern is to store a reference to the parent scope. something like `var ec = this;` at the top of the controller

Comment: True, for controllerAs sometimes people use something like `var $ctrl = this;` and then attach everything to `$ctrl`.

Comment: Interesting approach with ec var referencing this.  I'll definitely have to try that one.  Thanks, Prof Allman.

Answer (score 0):

if you put

```
var vm = this;
```

you can use vm instead of this anywhere! :)